# Inheriting from Vertex in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

All,

I am attempting to write some generic Java code using OrientDB. Specifically what I want to be able to do is to use the Graph DB for navigation, but for each graph element to hold a richer object to which responsibility is delegated when I need to access the properties.

The Vertices will hold quite a variety of object types (Vertices in their own right). However I have run into an issue.

Vertex is an interface only
OrientVertex is a class but is marked as final, so I can't inherit from it.

Is there a standard way in Java for a kind of hybrid model where the structures are graph elements (Vertices) with associated edges and the objects they hold on to are either Documents or Vertex instances?

Thanks in advance

C

Answer (score 0):

With the new release of OrientDB 3.0 a new model has been introduced: Multi-Model API. With this Java API, you can use OrientDB as a Document-Graph Database, allowing you to work with Vertices, Edges or simple Documents.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Java-MultiModel-API.html

Hope it helps

Regards